# Advice parsing dynamic SQL query with aggregate functions into JSON set of arrays

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, timescaledb

I need to parse the output of `time_bucket` ([TimescaleDB function](https://docs.timescale.com/latest/api#time_bucket) derivated from postgres [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC)) into a JSON object of arrays. I'm doing this for the first time and after lots of researching I have come with that:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION timescale.get_chronograph_json_time_bucket(
    _ts_start timestamp without time zone,
    _ts_end timestamp without time zone,
    _y1_name text,
    _y2_name text,
    _tb_name text,
    _time_bucket interval)
    RETURNS json
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    COST 100
    VOLATILE PARALLEL UNSAFE
AS $BODY$
DECLARE
    chronograph json;
BEGIN
EXECUTE '
    CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_table ON COMMIT DROP AS
    SELECT
        time_bucket($3,timestamp) AS bucket,
        avg('|| quote_ident(_y1_name) ||') AS y1,
        avg('|| quote_ident(_y2_name) ||') AS y2
    FROM timescale.' || quote_ident(_tb_name) ||'
    WHERE timestamp BETWEEN $1 AND $2
    GROUP BY bucket ORDER BY bucket'
USING _ts_start, _ts_end, _time_bucket;
SELECT json_build_object(
    'ts',json_agg(bucket),
    'y1',json_agg(y1),
    'y2',json_agg(y2))
FROM tmp_table
INTO chronograph;
RETURN chronograph;
END
$BODY$;
```

It returns the all the rows of the user requested variables(`_y1_name`, `_y2_name`) inside the specified timestamp range (`_ts_start`, `_ts_end`) with the requested resolution (`_time_bucket`) from the requested project (`_tb_name`).

It's doing the job but there are some "problems" that bother me:

1. Is it necessary to create a temporal table? What if there are two simultaneous calls to the function, wouldn't they share the same temporal table?
2. The `INTO chronograph; RETURN chronograph;` also looks kinda weird. There isn't a more direct way to return the JSON object?
3. This example is with a request of two variables but, how could I generalize this scheme to be able to answer to *from 1 to n* variables requests?

Comment: No, the temp table is not necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not necessary to create the temporary table. And yes, the `execute '...' into some_variable` is the only way to store the result of a (dynamic) SQL statement into a variable.

When building dynamic SQL is usually better to use the `format()` function. It makes the actual SQL easier to read and it can also deal with identifiers properly.

Dollar quoted strings can be nested by using different tags, which makes embedding single quotes in the actual SQL string easier.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION timescale.get_chronograph_json_time_bucket(
    _ts_start timestamp without time zone,
    _ts_end timestamp without time zone,
    _y1_name text,
    _y2_name text,
    _tb_name text,
    _time_bucket interval)
  RETURNS json
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE
    chronograph json;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format($sql$
    SELECT json_build_object(
        'ts',json_agg(bucket),
        'y1',json_agg(y1),
        'y2',json_agg(y2))
    FROM (
      SELECT
          time_bucket($3,timestamp) AS bucket,
          avg(%I) AS y1,
          avg(%I) AS y2
      FROM timescale.%I
      WHERE timestamp BETWEEN $1 AND $2
      GROUP BY bucket ORDER BY bucket
    ) tmp
    $sql$, _y1_name, _y2_name, _tb_name)
    INTO chronograph
    USING _ts_start, _ts_end, _time_bucket;
    
  RETURN chronograph;
END
$BODY$;
```

In theory this could be extended to loop over a list of column names and build the whole SQL string in that loop to deal with a variable list of columns.

Comment: Now, seem like this, looks simple and obvious. Thanks for your help, this will allow me to continue for further learning.